# SSL configuration in glassfish

Tags: configuration, ssl, glassfish

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kalali/archive/2010/02/27/how-install-godaddy-certificate-your-glassfish-v3

i have followed this article .

successfully downloaded certificates from verisign .downloaded trial certificates.

now when i try to get using https:// it shows connection not found..

temporarily i have created 192.1.200.104 alias of certificate.

and my machine's ip is the same.

now what domain i should configure  i have given  www.xxx.com while retrieving certificate.

if i need to create www.xx.com in my local glassfish server then how to configure domain ?

Thankx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now when i try to get using https:// it shows connection not found..

What URL did you use exactly? Did you try https://<server>:8181/ where <server> is the hostname of your server (if resolved properly)? If you followed the exact steps of the posted link, this should work.

> now what domain i should configure i have given www.xxx.com while retrieving certificate.

The resolution of www.xxx.com into your machine IP should be done at the DNS level (you can add the name into your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) for testing though). To be honest, I'm not sure I understood the question, I'm just assuming you don't need "virtual hosting".

Comment: ok thats what i was intended to ask.
do i need virtual server or not ?

thanks let me try.

Comment: @abc You don't need virtual hosting if you don't plan to serve several domains from this glassfish (and you don't seem to).

Comment: incase i want to test in my local machine which is not in network then how can i test it ?

Comment: i have my given my host name while getting certificate www.xxx.com and i have added host entry www.xxx.com with my IP.
and also imported root and intermediate certificate in FF still


The connection was interrupted

      

      
      
      

      
        
        

          

The connection to www.xxx.com:4848 was interrupted while the page was loading.

Comment: @abs can you ping www.xxx.com?

Comment: with http its working for admin console only its not working for web app also.
with https its not working for all (admin console and web app)

Comment: @abc Maybe you messed up http-connectors. Hard to say without seeing anything. Maybe start over with a fresh install.

Comment: http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/getting-started-with-glassfish-v3-and-ssl/

followed this.
installed newer glassfish v3 .
created newer domain domain2
retrieved certificate from thawte.
again same thing.
https:// not working.

connection interrupted.

Comment: also imported test root cert in FF

Comment: keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias www.xxx.com -keyalg RSA -dname "CN=www.xxx.com,O=yourCompany,L=yourCity,S=yourState,C=IN" -keypass pass -storepass pass -keystore final.keystore

keytool -certreq -alias www.xxx.com -keystore final.keystore -storepass pass -keypass pass -file server-2048.csr 

submitted this CSR to thwate's csr box.

Comment: Glassfish was not listed so selected other . and written sun glassfish
they mailed me 2 crt.
1. my certificate
2. testrootCA

imported these in final keystore using
keytool -import -alias root -keystore final.keystore -trustcacerts -file testCAROOT.crt

keytool -import -alias www.xxx.com -keystore final.keystore -trustcacerts -file mycert.crt

Comment: each time i get the same thing server not found.

Comment: SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path server.keystore due to Keystore was tampered with, or password was in
correct
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
       
May 3, 2010 3:37:24 PM com.sun.grizzly.config.SSLConfigHolder configureSSL
WARNING: SSL support could not be configured!C
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed

Comment: solved by changing keystore's password.
now on console i am constantly getting
 SEVERE: ProtocolChain exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CipherSuites may not be null
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuiteList.<init>(CipherSuiteList.java:58)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(SSLEngineImpl.java:1696)
        at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.newSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:358)
 </b>

Comment: @abc I'll try to write a kind of tutorial later this day, I've already done this and I didn't face all the problems you're referring to. That's the best I can do.

Comment: BTW pascal if i want to secure certain pages only then how to achieve this configuration ?

Comment: hey that error gone upon fresh installation of GF.  


Thanks  
can we secure certain pages only ?  
means supose i have a page say login.xhtml in my application then that page must be communcated over HTTPS and rest are on HTTP.

Comment: @abc That's typically something that you would enforce using rewrite rules (when using an Apache frontend). Without Apache, you could use a filter for that or the existing [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/).

Comment: Hey Pascal thanks a lot i am finally done.  
i have created a document
http://www.4shared.com/document/J1248lc7/SSL_Configuration_with_Glassfi.html
  
Thanks a ton.